# how cani replace @timestamp with log timestamp

Tags: timestamp, logstash

My sample log line -

```
14.111.26.41,22-MAY-17 20:33:09.694262,325711349,k101P481,1,2,1,1,1
             --------------------------
                   access_date
```

My filter in logstash is like below

```
date {      
     match => [ "access_date","dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss Z"]        
     target => "@timesstamp"
     }
```

Could you please help and let me know, where am I going wring here.

Comment: Use `dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSS`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match.

Comment: There is a typo in  `target => "@timesstamp"`, there are 2 S

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATED

My apology with confusion.
I have re-tested on *logstash 5.4.0* and come up with simple solution.

First , logstash date filter does not parse micro second.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match

> fraction of a second Maximum precision is milliseconds (SSS). Beyond
>   that, zeroes are appended.

So, below code will not parse **22-MAY-17 20:33:09.694262**

```
  date {
    match => ["access_date", "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
  }
```

It will result in

```
{
           "path" => "/tmp/sample.csv",
     "@timestamp" => 2017-10-10T08:18:39.777Z,
    "access_date" => "22-MAY-17 20:33:09.694262",
       "@version" => "1",
           "host" => "localhost.localdomain",
        "message" => "22-MAY-17 20:33:09.694262",
           "tags" => [
        [0] "_dateparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

If you want to use the logstash *date filter* , then you will need to slim the *microsec* to *milisec* and then parse with *SSS*.

```
{
           "path" => "/tmp/sample.csv",
     "@timestamp" => 2017-05-22T11:33:09.694Z,
    "access_date" => "22-MAY-17 20:33:09.694",
       "@version" => "1",
           "host" => "localhost.localdomain",
        "message" => "22-MAY-17 20:33:09.694"
}
```